# Unexpected behavior on fopen

Tags: c

I face a weird bug that I can't really explain. I am pretty sure the issue is a misunderstanding from my side but I can't find it.

I am writing a small application that requires a config file at the root of the home folder of the user (just like any .bashrc or .vim file).

To retrieve the full path of the file, I concat the HOME env variable with a `static const char*`.
The final function look like this:

```c
const char    *get_config_pathname(const char *pathname)
{
    char* homepath = getenv("HOME");
    if (homepath == NULL) {
       // ...
    }
    char* path = malloc((strlen(pathname) + strlen(homepath) + 2) * sizeof(char));
    strcat(path, homepath);
    strcat(path + strlen(homepath), "/");
    strcat(path + strlen(homepath) + 1, pathname);
    return path;
}
```

The output of the function is correct. I get the expect result without any '\n' or unexpected char.

However, when trying to use the value in `fopen` I got a error code 2 file not found.

- This fail:

```c
    fd = fopen(get_config_pathname(pathname), "r");
    if (fd == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening '[%s]' ; ERROR=%d\n", get_config_pathname(pathname), errno);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

// OUTPUT => Error opening [/home/dlacreme/.magic_bar] ; ERROR=2 ...
```

- This is successful:

```c
    fd = fopen("/home/dlacreme/.magic_bar", "r");
    if (fd == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening '[%s]' ; ERROR=%d\n", get_config_pathname(pathname), errno);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

At the end, both strings have the same value, I am not sure why one fails and not the other?

Thanks for your help

EDIT: project code source: https://github.com/Dlacreme/magicbar/ . The file https://github.com/Dlacreme/magicbar/blob/master/config.c

Comment: The data at `path` is not initialized before `strcat(path, homepath);`. Change it to `strcpy`. The data may contain nonprinting characters that are not visible in the error message you print but that make the path name wrong.

Comment: You are calling `get_config_pathname` twice. You might see a different output in the error message, than the actual filename passed to `fopen` that caused the error.

Comment: I'd use `sprintf` to build the full path. One line and done.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I see a lot of good suggestion, I expected modern compiler to clean the memory (didn't write C for a few years). I will probably replace the whole thing with sprintf. Not sure why I didn't think of that before.

Comment: You should never assume that a compiler, no matter how modern, will "clean the memory".

Comment: `I expected modern compiler to clean the memory  ...` That would be a disaster: all the memory would be faulted in.

Comment: @wildplasser: I've used an environment that does clean all the memory. On the assumption that you allocate memory with the intent to use it; all the pagefaults aren't a problem.

Comment: If this is for linux, I would just use `asprintf`.

Comment: @Joshua : in that case he *could* use `calloc()` [ or Read The Fine Manual]

Answer (score 2):

```
strcat(path, homepath);
```

This isn't right. Should start with `strcpy` because the contents of the return from `malloc` are uninitalized. There's better ways to write this but I'm not getting into that today.

Error 2 = ENOENT = no such file or directory.

Seems about right.

(you probably have a non-printable character at the start of path, so when you printed it you didn't see it)